# How do I encrypt the DB columns of type 'Integer', 'Date & Time Stamps' in Rails 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[image]

Postgres Database

I want to encrypt these pointed column values which are either Integer, timestamp.

I do not have the clear idea about how to encrypt multiple columns together.

I am using Rails 7, Active Record encryption but it seems that the non-text values cannot be directly encrypted.

So my code for the Model is, (just an example) about how I am trying to encrypt the values.

```
Class People < ApplicationRecord
  encrypts :religion, :caste, deterministic: true
```

Comment: You don't indicate what the underlying database is, but given this situation it might be better to let the database engine handle the encryption and decryption.

Comment: Edited in the question, it's a Postgres database. Kindly tell how to do it now

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/encryption-options.html

Comment: Yeah I am actually using PgCrypto. Do you have any idea that how can we encrypt the existing Database Tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use text data type for encryption. additionally you can use "deterministic: true" to query for the data.

Answer (score 1):

When using ActiveRecord Encryption you store the data in VARCHAR/TEXT columns regardless of what type you intend to use for the attribute.

What you're storing is the result of serializing the data and then passing it into encryption algorthim which produces a string. When reading data Rails decrypts the attribute and then deserializes it and you get [values typecast into the intended type](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_encryption.html#supported-types).

This isn't really unique to Rails - its how application side data encryption works in general. The alternative is database side encryption but thats a completely different question.

Comment: Did not understand your point, So what should I do to encrypt the Integer and timestamp values?

Comment: Use a TEXT column. Not an integer column. I thought that was abundantly clear.

Comment: Sorry my bad I am very new to rails and a recently made jr. dev, but the DB is already seeded and the columns in the mnigration are of integer and timestamps. 

So what changes do I need to make in my code to make it compatible for integer and timestamps. Yeah, I read that the columns should be of TEXT type for the encrypted values.

I cannot change the DB column types, so is there a way around using which I can make this work for the integer and timestamps?

Please pardon me, I'm confused.

Comment: You're still not listening. I understand that you're a junior but you have to realize that not everything is fixable by copying some magic snippet. Sometimes you actually have to understand the underpinnings of what it is you're doing. What you're trying to do isn't even theoretically possible. Change the column type or abandon the idea of application side encryption.

Comment: Yeah sorry, yesterday I understood that, to get the encrypted values I have to change the DB Column type else it would not be possible. It took me some time but thanks for reminding me again, I will do as mentioned.